# How do I get the background-color value?

Tags: javascript, css, styles

```
<input class="color" value="66ff00" id="fc" autocomplete="off" style="background-image: none; background-color: rgb(128, 225, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

How can I get the value of the `background-color`?

Everytime I use `(element).attr("background-color")`, it doesn't work. I suppose it has to do with `style="background-color"`.

Comment: u mean Retrieving background-color Property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
(element).css("background-color");
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Does this give the value of the b-c?

Comment: yes that will give bg color
or if u dont want to use jquery u can do it with js too refer my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can access any css property via [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(".color").css('background-color')
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fy14us5e/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.css` method to fetch the background colour, ie:

```
$(element).css('background-color');
```

You may also access it without quoting, using the object:

```
$(element).css(bgColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any css property in jQuery then use

```
$(selector).css(property);
```

Here, in this case it is `$("#fc").css('background-color');`

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will work..

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
alert($("#fc").css('background-color'));
});
</script>

<input class="color" value="66ff00" id="fc" autocomplete="off" style="background-image: none; background-color: rgb(128, 225, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work you will get the backround color of #fc

```
var fc = document.getElementById('fc');
var bgcolor = fc.style.backgroundColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input.color").css("background-color");
```

It will return you the specified background-color.

and then do this to get the result:

```
var color = $("input.color").css("background-color"); 

$("$target_element").css("background-color", color);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use .css property to get specific css value using id or class selector.

`$("#fc").css('background-color')` // fc is the id for the control

or

`$(".color").css('background-color')` //color is the class applied here